# Get hourly breakdown of records in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a database with sales record and want to compute the hourly breakdown of number of sales.The column is int format(unix time stamp).

```
DATE: 1499709653 , ORDER_ID : 10 , etc..
```

This can be done by executing queries for each hour or simply get the records for the day and do it programatically. But is there a away in MySql to get the number of records in each hour as a break down with one query.

Comment: you want to group your data by hour, and count the records, correct?

Comment: yes, group by the hour and get the total record count which is in the unix time stamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then something like:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(DATE), '%Y%m%d%H') AS 'Time'
       , COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
  FROM YourTable
 GROUP BY 1
```

For more Information check out the mySQL documentation of [Date an Time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)